# Double Calendar invites from Exchange server

Tags: macos, calendar

I am running macOS 10.13.4 and recently when I am getting calendar invites from an exchange server, the invites are doubling up. In other words, I am seeing two of everything and am forced to accept both, so I end up with double events in my iCal. If I delete either, it sends a decline.

How can I prevent double invites?

Comment: Can you check your accounts preferences? Perhaps you have two accounts that are receiving the same invites, or a duplicate account (I'm not sure that's possible though).